# SUM a specific column in next rows until a condition is true

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is a table of articles and I want to store sum of **Mass Column** from **next rows** in **sumNext Column** based on a condition.

If next row has same floor (in floorNo column) as current row, then add the mass of next rows until the floor is changed

E.g : Rows three has **sumNext = 2**. That is computed by adding the mass from row four and row five because both rows has **same floor** number as row three.

| id | mass | symbol | floorNo | sumNext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2891176 | 1 | D | 1 | 0 |
| 2891177 | 1 | L | 8 | 0 |
| 2891178 | 1 | L | 1 | **2** |
| 2891179 | **1** | L | 1 | 1 |
| 2891180 | **1** |  | 1 | 0 |
| 2891181 | 1 |  | 5 | 2 |
| 2891182 | 1 |  | 5 | 1 |
| 2891183 | 1 |  | 5 | 0 |

Here is the query, that is generating this table, I just want to add sumNext column with the right value inside.

```
WITH items AS (SELECT 
SP.id,
    SP.mass,
    SP.symbol,
    SP.floorNo
FROM articles SP
        ORDER BY  
          DECODE(SP.symbol,
            'P',1,
            'D',2,
            'L',3,
              4 ) asc)
SELECT CLS.*
FROM items CLS;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use below solution which uses

- ***common table expression*** (cte) technique to put all consecutive rows with same FLOORNO value in the same group (new grp column).
- Then uses the analytic version of SUM function to sum all next MASS per grp column as required.

```sql
Items_RowsNumbered (id, mass, symbol, floorNo, rnb) as (
  select ID, MASS, SYMBOL, FLOORNO
    , row_number()over( 
          order by DECODE(symbol, 'P',1, 'D',2, 'L',3, 4 ) asc, ID )
  /*
    You need to add ID column (or any others columns that can identify each row uniquely)
    in the "order by" clause to make the result deterministic
    */
  from (Your source query)Items
)
, cte(id, mass, symbol, floorNo, rnb, grp) as (
  select id, mass, symbol, floorNo, rnb, 1 grp
  from Items_RowsNumbered
  where rnb = 1
  union all
  select t.id, t.mass, t.symbol, t.floorNo, t.rnb
    , case when t.floorNo = c.floorNo then c.grp else c.grp + 1 end grp
  from Items_RowsNumbered t
  join cte c on (c.rnb + 1 = t.rnb)
)
select 
    ID, MASS, SYMBOL, FLOORNO
  /*, RNB, GRP*/
  , nvl(
        sum(MASS)over(
          partition by grp
            order by rnb 
              ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       , 0 
      ) sumNext
from cte
;
```

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03e0647db8487597e30a6bad79136802)

Comment: This one worked in my case, Thanks

Comment: Glad to see I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical `gaps-and-islands` problem. You can use `LAG()` in order to determine the exact partitions, and then `SUM()` analytic function such as

```sql
WITH ii AS
(
 SELECT i.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY floorNo ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn1
   FROM items i
)
SELECT id,mass,symbol, floorNo, 
       SUM(mass) OVER (PARTITION BY rn2-rn1 ORDER BY id DESC)-1 AS sumNext
  FROM ii 
 ORDER BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=082de09b3398e6223e2e42e9b0e8f69c)</kbd>

Comment: but order should not involve the ID column, it should be according to a custom alphabets in symbol column DECODE(SP.symbol,
            'P',1,
            'D',2,
            'L',3,
              4 )